# <body> with overflow:scroll not behaving as expected

Tags: html, css

Look at the following image and code:

[image]

```
<!doctype html>

<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            body {
                border: 1px solid red;
                padding: 20px;
                overflow: scroll;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body></body>
</html>
```

The `overflow: scroll` inserts scroll bars inside the element, but the `<body>` element doesn't occupy the entire webpage, what is wrong with the scroll bars?

Thanks

Comment: You are setting body's overflow : scroll . Body occupies all web page (`width and height always 100%`) and scrolls showing as you want. So ? What is the problem ?

Comment: I think he wants the body to be 100% the height of the view portal, but in reality this body likely stops before it consumes the whole web browser view portal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `body` tag is kind of a special case.  Most style rules applied to the `body` tag apply to the whole window, regardless of tho `body`'s "size".  For the behavior you want (a scrollbar inside a box), you'll need to use a `div` or some other block-level element inside of the `body`.

Answer (score 10):

`overflow:scroll` will add scrollbars whether the body is bigger than the window or not. You are probably looking for `overflow:auto;`

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `overflow: auto;` instead of `overflow: scroll;`
Check it out here. http://jsfiddle.net/w6B6z/

Answer (score 0):

The body height is not set to 100%.  Even with the body height set to 100%, for this to work correctly, you need to call a few items in CSS to make it all work out cross browser.

[Look to 100% Height Layout Using CSS](http://www.dave-woods.co.uk/index.php/100-height-layout-using-css/comment-page-4/) for the details.