# Resize browser during onload

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Through various research online, I found out that user are not able to resize the browser anymore through `window.resizeTo(200,200)` function or `changeScreenSize(200,200)` because the browser maker had disabled it.

I'm trying to design a keypad using html. And my keypad is not suppose to fill the whole screen. It only uses less than half of the browser screen. Do you guys have any idea how to resize the browser window?

Comment: **resizeTo** will resize the window which is been opened using **window.open**
As per your requirment, you dont need to use ant resize events..you can design your page that way.

Comment: I tried but it won't work. I put like this <body onload="window.resizeTo(200,200)"> but it won't work. Any idea why?

Comment: I dont find any need to use this method as per your requirment..

Comment: @Coolguy hi first calculate the height and width from your created function in window.load method and while opening that window using windiw.open just pass that parameters adding **resizable=yes** so might it can't get prefect heigth with it can be manually adjustable

Answer (score 1):

> **You cant resize window.**

As per [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/resizeTo) documentation, you cant resize window if it is parent window.

> **Then how can I resize?**

Even though you can't resize window size, but you can resize any DOM element. One solution is wrap all body html code into a div, and resize that div. [Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/E1kH102hBVjWFI3RMUkJ?p=preview) is a simple demo. 
**Dont think about resizing body, as body is special DOM and you cant set overflow scroll to it. As per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4998334/2034794) answer.**

> Here is code

```js
// Code goes here

$(function() {
  $("#btnExpand").on("click", function() {
    $(".container").height(1000);
  });
  $("#btnCollapse").on("click", function() {
    $(".container").height(500);
  });
});
```

```css
.container {
  overflow: scroll;
  height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <button id="btnExpand">Expand</button>
  <button id="btnCollapse">Collapse</button>
  <ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>1</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**This will not resize your browser window. But this will resize viewport on which your page is going to display**

Comment: THANK YOU for spelling this out. I was wondering about it because I remember it used to be possible and I could not find any current documentation how to accomplish this.  This is what I needed to see to confirm my suspicions that it wasn't permissible any longer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
window.open("title", "", "width=200, height=100");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7Le8mgqf/

Comment: on click event onto which you want this window to open like 

$(button).click(function(){
window.open("title", "", "width=200, height=100");
})

incase you are using jquery

Comment: I'm not opening a pop up and I don't do it in click event. How do I do it if I want to resize when the page load?

Comment: then put this in onload function simply , in javascript file

Comment: I put already window.open("title", "", "width=200, height=100"); into onload and it just pop up a new window. But I want my original window to resize.

Comment: @Coolguy, dont use window.open, it create popup, and most of the browsers block the popup window. this solution is to resize popup window, not the parent window.

Comment: Then how do I resize the parent window during onload?